# how to make a category of product visible in menu in all pages in django

Tags: django

html inside layouts and i make extends in other pages, all work fine but category menu (come from database) is hidden in some pages and i can see it just in one pages there is my code :

```
def produit_list(request):
    produits = Produits.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
                'produits':produits,
                'categories':categories,
    
            }
    return render(request, 'shop.html', context)


#categories.html
<div class="col-md-4 pt-5">
    <h2 class="h2 text-light border-bottom pb-3 border-light">Categories</h2>
    <ul class="list-unstyled text-light footer-link-list">
    {% for cat in categories %}
            <li><a class="text-decoration-none" href="#">{{cat.name}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

i include this code inside base.html

i want know how to load it in all website like menu in bottom of every page, now i can see it just in shop.html.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a **custom context processor** or with **custom template tags**.

**1- pass it through custom context processor**

create a custom context processor file and a function.

```
# the custom_context.py file

def global_ctx():
   return {
     # any other values ...
     "categories": Category.objects.all(),
   }
```

add this file in your `settings.py` file under the `TEMPLATES` section as

```
 TEMPLATES = [
     {
         "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
         "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
         "APP_DIRS": True,
         "OPTIONS": {
             "context_processors": [
                 "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                 "django.template.context_processors.request",
                 "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                 "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                 "App_Name.custom_context.global_ctx",  # Custom Context Processor
             ],
         },
     },
 ]
```

and you are good to go, you can access the `categories` in all of your template files.

**2- pass it through custom tags**

under your app create a `templatetags` directory. and create your custom tag file inside.

```
# the your_app/templatetags/custom_tag.py file
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_categories():
    return Category.objects.all()
```

then in your `html` file, first load the custom tag `{% load custom_tag %}` then you can access it.
[this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) could help you more on custom template tags and filters.

Answer (score 0):

Do it through a context processor

```
# Create a context_processors.py in your django app
def produit_list(request):
    produits = Produits.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'produits':produits,
        'categories':categories,
    }
    # Return a dictionary with the data you want to load 
    # on every request call or every page.
    return context
```

And in your settings:

```
# ...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                # ...
                "your_app.context_processors.produit_list",
                # ...
            ],
        },
    }
]

# ...
```

Then you can call produits and categories on every page you want, just like you are doing it in your categories.html